# Background job to get O365 users gets unauthorized exception

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

We are trying to create a microservice module whose job is to fetch all users using Microsoft Graph API (/users/) once a day and do something with them.

We have followed the guide here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service and granted the Azure APP the Read.User.All permission: [image]

We then had an admin consent to this permission from the Azure Blade.

Our service uses the Microsoft.Identity.Client lib to get the token:

```
var confidentialClientApplication = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
            this.applicationId,
            this.authority,
            this.redirectUri,
            this.credential,
            new TokenCache(),
            new TokenCache());

            var result = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });
            return result.AccessToken;
```

Then we create the Graph client:

```
new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
            async requestMessage =>
            {
                var graphToken = await this.graphAuthProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync();

                // Append the access token to the request
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", graphToken);
            }));
```

Below is the payload of the token I get back (some info omitted)

```
{
 "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
 "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/<tenant_id>/",
 "iat": 1527833423,
 "nbf": 1527833423,
 "exp": 1527837323,
 "aio": "Y2dgYKgxbYzssLvLWfve6WbgtsdWAA==",
 "app_displayname": "<app_name>",
 "appid": "<app_id>",
 "appidacr": "1",
 "e_exp": 262800,
 "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/<tenant_id>/",
 "oid": "<subject_id>",
 "sub": "<subject_id>",
 "tid": "<tenant_id>",
 "uti": "-XvIySkmuUOuqmQI0l8CAA",
 "ver": "1.0"
}
```

And then trying to get the Users I receive an error saying the application doesn't have permission to access that resource.

Comment: Can you please add a copy of the token you're getting back to your question?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I have edited the post with the payload of the token (I have inserted placeholders for some information)

Answer (score 1):

Found what was wrong. Turns out I was adding Delegated Permissions instead of Application permissions.